# Where is the executable zplug file in Ubuntu after apt install zplug?

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, apt

I'm trying to test my dotfiles in ubuntu (in a docker container);

I'm using zplug, I already installed it via `sudo apt install zplug`, but the path isn't set properly (`zsh: command not found: zplug`).

So which directory has to be added to path to run zplug?

Comment: `dpkg -S zplug` will show you all the files that were installed by the package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found init.zsh in `/usr/share/zplug/init.zsh`
So, after `$ source /usr/share/zplug/init.zsh` I have zplug available